# Ordenamiento de texto

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

En un formulario tengo un textarea al momento de ingresar data la ingreso de la siguiente forma.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo llamo desde la base datos me tira como una linea 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma como dejarlo ordenados como los ingreso al principio?Estoy usando codeigniter. Espero haberme explicado bien saludos.

Comment: A que te refieres con ordenamiento? a ordenar alfabeticamente el texto o a ordenar la posicion que se presenta el texto?

Comment: ordenar la presentación del texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr presentar los datos de la manera que quieres, podrías usara la función [`explode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) y luego recorrer los datos en un `foreach` para agregarles un salto de linea. Algo así:

```
$s = "-Requerimiento 1 -Requerimiento 2 -Requerimiento 3";

$r = explode("-",$s);

foreach($r as $key => $value){
    if($value != null){
      echo $value."<br/>";  
    }
}
```

Esto te devolvera:

```
Requerimiento 1 
Requerimiento 2 
Requerimiento 3
```

Comment: vaya que fácil, funciono de maravilla. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo te lo agradezco mucho :)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en un textarea los saltos de línea se establecen con el comando "\n". Si tú pintas este string en un navegador no verás este salto de línea ya que en html el salto de línea es el tag `<br>`.

Si en el textarea escribes `-requerimiento1 <br> -requerimiento2 <br> ...`verás como luego si que se te refleja el salto de línea.

Debes convertir los \n en `<br>`. Esto lo puedes hacer antes de subir el formulario en javascript. Antes de guardarlo en db en PHP o al leerlo antes de usar el dato.

Para cambiar los códigos en javascript:

```
... HTML ...
<textarea id="userText"></textarea>

.... JS ....
//con jQuery    
var value = $('#userText').val();

//sin jQuery
var value = document.getElementById('userText').value;
```

En PHP hay varias alternativas. Sustituye caracteres con str_replace por ejemplo.